# Distorted video playback: can't see the movie

Tags: video

Some videos on my laptop appear like this when played

[image: screenshot of distorted video]

I tried to download the same video in the image from youtube agent. It worked fine when I watched it online, but after downloading it, I still had the same problem.

Comment: What Youtube agent?

Comment: i mean the video is not brokin

Comment: Is it just with VLC player?

Comment: no with Totem Movie Player too

Comment: it worked fine after i tried to edit it with pitivi video editor

Comment: i think if i delete sound attachments in ubuntu and redownload them it will fix the problem
put i don,t know how

Answer (score 1):

i know how to fix the problem
go to tools > preferences > video settings

in display
change output to > X11 video output

it worked fin after that

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Glad you found a solution!